# First experiment calling asynch method - Do I need ALL this code?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, delegates

Never tried asynch calling with Windows Form. I cannot use the new `aynch/await` because I don't own recent Visual Studio/.NET. What I need is "execute an operation that request long time (populate an IList)" and, when it has finished, write on a TextBox the result of that list.

Searching on Internet I found this example that seems work, but TOO comply in my opinion (maybe there are somethings fast and simple):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTaskAsync();
}

private void MyTaskWorker()
{
    // here I populate the list. I emulate this with a sleep of 3 seconds
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}

private delegate void MyTaskWorkerDelegate();

public void MyTaskAsync()
{
    MyTaskWorkerDelegate worker = new MyTaskWorkerDelegate(MyTaskWorker);
    AsyncCallback completedCallback = new AsyncCallback(MyTaskCompletedCallback);

    AsyncOperation async = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
    worker.BeginInvoke(completedCallback, async);
}

private void MyTaskCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    MyTaskWorkerDelegate worker = (MyTaskWorkerDelegate)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
    AsyncOperation async = (AsyncOperation)ar.AsyncState;

    worker.EndInvoke(ar);

    AsyncCompletedEventArgs completedArgs = new AsyncCompletedEventArgs(null, false, null);
    async.PostOperationCompleted(delegate(object e) { OnMyTaskCompleted((AsyncCompletedEventArgs)e); }, completedArgs);
}

public event AsyncCompletedEventHandler MyTaskCompleted;

protected virtual void OnMyTaskCompleted(AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyTaskCompleted != null)
        MyTaskCompleted(this, e);

    // here I'll populate the textbox
    textBox1.Text = "... content of the Iteration on the List...";
}
```

really I NEED somethings like 50 lines of code for this easy operation? Or I can remove some stuff? I just need a simple asynch call->callback when finished.

No lock, no concurrency at all...

Comment: I would just get [VS 2012 express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express), unless you have other constraints besides not having the latest version.

Comment: It is not a good idea to make the UI thread sleep for 3 seconds! this means that your UI is freezed for three seconds. Besids, having hardcoded values in the code is also not recommended, there is certainly a more elegant way without harcoded values.

Comment: @Siraf: is what I want to emulate :) This example works, the UI is not freezed, because asynch.

Comment: @Siraf The `Thread.Sleep` isn't run in the UI; it's run in a thread pool thread.  This examples is excessively verbose and could be made quite a lot simpler, but there's nothing *wrong* with any of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the TPL with C# 4.0 like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork())
        .ContinueWith(t => UpdateUIWithResults(t.Result)
        , CancellationToken.None
        , TaskContinuationOptions.None
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

This starts `DoWork` in a thread pool thread, allowing it to do processing out of the UI thread, then runs `UpdateUIWithResults` in a UI thread, passing it the results of `DoWork`.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to works! Dunno why this yes and @Stephen Cleary not: looks the same :O

Comment: @markzzz His doesn't work for exactly the reason I said in my comment to his answer; he doesn't execute the continuation on the UI thread, and he should.  My answer differs solely in that I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Task.Factory.StartNew` to push work onto the thread pool. `Task.ContinueWith` will give you a "completed callback".

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task<List<T>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyTaskWorker());
    task.ContinueWith(t => OnMyTaskCompleted(t), ui);
}

private List<T> MyTaskWorker()
{
    // here I populate the list. I emulate this with a sleep of 3 seconds
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    return ...;
}

protected virtual void OnMyTaskCompleted(Task t)
{
    // here I'll populate the textbox with t.Result
    textBox1.Text = "... content of the Iteration on the List...";
}
```

Comment: You need to ensure that the callback is executed on the UI thread.  As it is, you'll get a cross thread exception.

Comment: @Servy: how can I ensure it? But in fact I don't want it, else the UI will freeze :P It is what I want to avoid...

Comment: @markzzz See my answer.  You want the method doing the background work to be in a background thread, but you need the method to update the UI with the results to be in the UI thread.  That's a very standard situation to be in.